# Which is the best JSON rewriter for Java?

Tags: java, json

Which JSON rewriter is the best for applications written in Java?  Criteria may vary.  I'm personally most interested in stability and performance.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the one from http://www.json.org. The direct link to the Java code is this: 
http://www.json.org/java/index.html.

The nice thing about it is that it does not require any dependencies. You just need to add seven source files to your project and you've got yourself a JSON builder.

Answer (score 1):

This one works just fine: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

This JsonTools library is very complete. You can find it at [Berlios](http://jsontools.berlios.de/).